# How is a Potential Difference Created in Photo Voltaic Cells?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, solar-cells

In order for photo cells to produce current, N and P type material are joined to create a depletion zone. I understand how incoming photons can dislodge electrons from their atoms in the N type material and cause forward bias. However, for a solar cell to work continuously, it must be connected from the P type back to the N type so the electrons are able to cycle.

In this system, what is preventing electrons from simply traveling from the N type material directly to the P type material without them jumping the junction?

(New here, please corrected me on formatting/typical nomenclature. Thanks.)

Comment: You misunderstand how a solar cell works. Photons absorbed in the depletion layer create electron-hole pairs, which head in different directions because of the built-in field. This provides the current. The circuit takes care of the electrons and holes meeting back up. Electrons have no desire to travel from the n to the p regions, since they have the same Fermi level in both, thanks to the depletion region.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jon. Are you saying that the photon absorption occurs in the depletion zone only? I thought that when the junction is made, an electrostatic field was created across the depletion zone. When an electron in the N type material is excited enough to overcome that electrostatic field it goes to the P type. Individually, each material is neutral, only together (due to their semi conductive nature) do they create said electric field. It is possible that I am still not conceptualizing the process of current generation in a photo cell. Do you think you could further clarify?

Comment: Current comes mainly from e-h pairs generated in the depletion layer. There is some contribution from the minority carriers from e-h pairs generated in the bulk layers that diffuse to the depletion region and are then swept across it by the built-in field. Electrons from n-type regions have no way to cross the junction.